# Using Attribute Selectors and then using a Pseudo Element

Tags: css, attributes, pseudo-element, radiobuttonlist, squarespace

So, I am using Squarespace to build a website, and for whatever reason, squarespace uses radio buttons for their nav (at least secondary nav) instead of

list items.

I am trying to make edits to the menu so that when you click on a menu item, it is essentially "checked" (since they use radio buttons) and then applies the CSS styling I would like.

I am, however, having some difficulty getting the menu items to retain their styling.

By using attribute selectors, I can select the menu items; however, I am having trouble selecting them to display only in the **:checked** state.

The reason I am having to use attribute selectors is because the class name that begins with "menu-select", has a string of numbers behind it that actually changes with every reload. So, every time I make any particular changes to the code to the full, numeric class name, upon the next reload, the changes do not stay because the class name (or numbers because that's what they are) has changed.

My question: Is there a way to use attribute selectors and then target pseudo elements?

I want to make changes to my CSS only in the :checked state.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
.menu-block .menu-selector label[class^="menu-select"] {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

But this is really what I want it to do:

```
.menu-block .menu-selector label[class^="menu-select"]:checked {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `label`s do not have a `:checked` pseudo-**class** , so It's a little unclear to me what you are trying to do. We need to see the HTML of the label/radio button.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Here's the site: karey-walker.squarespace.com/menu. `#menu-select-wine-list-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-ee32a03d-0682-4893-9a45‌​-cbb60dcc3019:checked ~ .menu-selector .menu-label-wine-list-yui_3_17_2_1_1412637006352_21955-ee32a03d-0682-4893-9a45-c‌​bb60dcc3019 { text-decoration: underline; }` 

This is the code I would like to change. However, my main problem is finding a way to select the ID that starts with `#menu-select` and ends with `:checked` because the string of numbers is changing after every reload so I can't pinpoint it. Maybe it's a JavaScript issue?Thanks!